# Infinite scrollable FlatList - Render ads/tips in between

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I am creating an e-commerce/trading feature in our app, Where user will be able to see available deals in an infinitely scrollable manner, I am using flatlist for this. Now, in between the posts, I want to show tips like - "post your own ad", "apply filters for better search results" etc.

The UI of these tips is different than the normal ad card component because I want to highlight these tips.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

My solutions is to insert these tips in the data array and add a isTip boolean, which I then check in the renderItem of flatlist.